# Using Directive vs Qualifier

Tags: c#, performance, configuration

I occasionally reference items that are only used once in a class.  These tend to be configuration calls, but this can apply to anything.

**Option 1)**

```
using System.Web.Configuration

private static readonly string conn = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration......
```

**Option 2)**

```
private static readonly string conn = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration.......
```

Option 1 has the benefit of easier readability and if I add other objects of the same type later I do not have as much to type.  This all follows the DRY principles.  Outside of that does anyone know I would like to know if there is a compilation difference between placing a using directive vs naming the full qualifier at the time of the variable creation.

Comment: Use what maximizes readability and maintainability in your environment. Even if there is a difference in compilation, who cares about a nanonsecond or two here and there?

Comment: @Pieter - Does not matter, was only a downvote in my mind ;). Not enough rep and cant downvote comments anyways.

Comment: OK. You would not believe the trouble I got into on meta for suggesting that downvotes be reduced in volume a bit.

Comment: Understandable, its hard to convey emotion in text.  I did not mean to be rude, that's why I removed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming both compile and end up referring to the same member - no, there's no difference.

You could end up with naming collisions if you create a type called `WebConfigurationManager` in a different namespace, but that's pretty rare.

It's almost *never* a good idea to use the fully-qualified name in the body of your code. Basically only for disambiguation, and even then there are alternatives, such as:

```
// Make sure it's really unique
using swc = global::System.Web.Configuration;
...

private static readonly string conn = swc::WebConfigurationManager.[...];
```

Comment: Hi Jon, Would you mind explaining the `global::` and `::` syntax in more detail, or providing a reference?  I can't find a reference to either of these on MSDN at either [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) or [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.71).aspx). (I would be honoured!)

Comment: @Sepster: It's a namespace alias qualifier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Thank you for adding the info about the alias.